# How to make the implicit ScrollViewer appear on the left hand side instead of right hand side

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ScrollViewer` which appears on the right hand side when enough objects are in the list. How can I make it appear on the left hand side?

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="MessageListBox" 
    BorderThickness="0" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
    AlternationCount="2" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AltStyle}" 
    SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- button -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I would caution moving this to the other side.  The normal implementation is right side and putting on the left may confuse / irritate your users.

Answer (score 15):

It can be achieved by wrapping the list into `ScrollViewer` and changing the `ScrollViewer` property `FlowDirection` to `RightToLeft`. Also don't forget to restore the lists `FlowDirection` to `LeftToRight` otherwise it will inherit the parent's direction.

```
<ScrollViewer FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
    CanContentScroll="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CustomItems}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I found it on MSDN social blogs, 
[How to Set VerticalScroll bar on Left side](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e796231d-5c92-44b4-bb7e-c3b74d81a99c/how-to-set-verticalscroll-bar-on-left-side?forum=wpf)

Comment: This will invert the contents of whatever control is in the SrollViewer.  So it could have hugely detrimental effects if you don't take that into consideration.

Comment: @claudekennilol - Actually, this works perfectly because they are setting the FlowDirect back to LeftToRight inside the listbox.  If there were lots of items you could also wrap them all inside of a grid.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols Right, should've pointed that out that *this* example does that, but it's good to point out for someone that doesn't know what it'll do overall.

Comment: This doesn't work because you loose the ability to move the scroll wheel on your items.

Answer (score 5):

This is accomplished by modifying the template of the ListBox's `ScrollViewer`.

Start by modifying the `ColumnDefinitions` for the container `Grid`. Then, put things into the correct columns.

Have fun!

```
<!--This should be able to be placed on any WPF Window for testing purposes-->
<ListBox Height="85" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="117,110,300,0">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                    
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <TextBox Text="Hi Mom!"/>
    <TextBox Text="Hi Dad!"/>
    <TextBox Text="Hi Father!"/>
    <TextBox Text="Hi Mother!"/>
    <TextBox Text="Hi Padre!"/>            
</ListBox>
```

P.S. If you wanted to move the `HorizontalScrollBar`, simply reorder the `RowDefinitions`, the do the same exercise (put every child component in the proper row)

Comment: The scrollbar appears, but it scrolling it does not scroll my data

Comment: Yeah, I noticed you were using a listbox, and editted the post correctly, you'll want to make sure it uses the itemspresenter that was there before.

Comment: And now I see you're in WPF... more changes coming.

Comment: IMO, using FlowDirection as proposed by @tequilacat, but inside the template (as you suggest) is a lot more intuitive than creating a grid with columns and everything in the template.

Comment: That's a lot of work for something that could be done just by reversing the FlowDirection.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to set `RightToLeft` `FlowDirection` for `ListView` and then set `LeftToRight` for `ItemsPanelTemplate` child `StackPanel`.

```
<ListView FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataSource}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Original `ListView` shown on the right and `ListView` with scrollbar positioned on the left (by source code above) - shown on the left.

[image: Original List View shown on the right and List View with scrollbar positioned on the left (by source code above) - shown on the left.]

Comment: this was the best performing answer for me

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the ListBox's embedded scrollviewer to RightToLeft:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
```